# Installing Visual Studio Code on RP3 is failing

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to get Microsoft Visual Studio Code on my Raspberry Pi3 running Raspbian 9 (stretch).  I've used these instructions; http://dattabase.com/install-vs-code-raspberry-pi-3/, except that I am using the n node manager and running node v 8.4.0 and npm v5.3.0.

When is run "./scripts/npm.sh install --arch=armhf" it runs for a while, then I get the following errors;

```
> electron-mksnapshot@1.7.1 install /home/pi/projects/vscode/node_modules/electron-mksnapshot
> node ./download-mksnapshot.js

/home/pi/projects/vscode/node_modules/electron-mksnapshot/download-mksnapshot.js:16
  if (error != null) throw error
                     ^

Error: Failed to find Electron v1.7.0 for linux-armhf at https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.7.0/mksnapshot-v1.7.0-linux-armhf.zip
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/pi/projects/vscode/node_modules/nugget/index.js:169:61)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/pi/projects/vscode/node_modules/nugget/node_modules/request/request.js:1074:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:565:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@0.3.8 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@0.3.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: windows-foreground-love@0.1.0 (node_modules/windows-foreground-love):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for windows-foreground-love@0.1.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: windows-mutex@0.2.0 (node_modules/windows-mutex):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for windows-mutex@0.2.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: windows-process-tree@0.1.6 (node_modules/windows-process-tree):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for windows-process-tree@0.1.6: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron-mksnapshot@1.7.1 install: `node ./download-mksnapshot.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-mksnapshot@1.7.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.electron-gyp/.npm/_logs/2017-09-16T23_48_28_562Z-debug.log
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your npm install is configured to look for packages of the 'linux-armhf' architecture; looking at the electrum releases for 1.7.0 shows that they only have 'linux-arm' and 'linux-armv7l.'

To fix this, you should just be able to do `npm install --arch=arm electron@1.7.0` to have it use one of the supported architecture releases; then re-run the script. (this may or may not work, depending on whether npm skips packages if a different architecture version is already installed)